How can multiple clones of the same project be distinguished in VsCode if they are opened in a similar devContainer?
Recently you can set workbench.editor.customLabels.patterns in Vscode to distinguish between editors with the same file names. And there is also the window.title option, which you can set to something like ${folderpath} to change the window title according to the currently opened file.
My problem is different however:
I have multiple clones of the same project in paths like bellow:

path/Desktop/Folder1/myProjectName
path/Desktop/Folder2/myProjectName
path/Desktop/Folder3/myProjectName

and the project opens directly a docker container.
In this case, if you enter pwd in the VsCode terminal, the path for all three projects is the path of the terminal inside the container (which is for all three the same), and not the path of the project itself. Therefore the VsCode settings options mentioned above do not work. Does anyone know a way to differentiate between the projects, in such situation, in the smartest way? (Of course you can add a dummy folder inside the project folders, but that's not what I'm interested in)
